# How do I change the html tag and class generated by fields_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, fields-for

This is a simple question that I'm kinda ashamed to ask, but I've been banging my head against the wall and navigating through the rails 3 documentation without any success :/

So, here is the thing:

When I use the `fields_for` helper it wraps the generated fields in a `<div class="fields"> ... </div>` tag.

so, my code is

```
<ul class="block-grid two-up">
  <%= f.fields_for :images do |image_builder| %>
    <%= render "images/form", :f => image_builder %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

and the generated html is:

```
<ul class="block-grid two-up">
  <div class="fields">
    <div>
      <label for="company_images_attributes_0_image"> Image</label>
      <input id="company_images_attributes_0_image" 
             name="company[images_attributes][0][image]" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fields">
    <div>
      <label for="company_images_attributes_1_image"> Image</label>
      <input id="company_images_attributes_1_image" 
             name="company[images_attributes][1][image]" type="file">
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is actually change the `<div class="fields">` wrapper tag to `<li>`.

The documentation says you can pass options to the fields_for, but its not clear about what options you can pass, maybe you can change this wrapper tag?

A possibility could be to override a function, kinda like `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc` when there is an error in the form.

Quick edit: I forgot to mention that I'm using simple_form to generate this form. I tried looking in the `simple_form.rb` config file for a way to customize this, but I didn't see any way of doing it.

**Solution**
After further investigation, it turns out the form was using the [nested_form](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem as well to generate the form (not only simple_form). This generator was causing the fields_for to be wrapped in the div tag. Thanks everybody for their suggestions!

Comment: The field_error_proc approach is canonical. (IIRC with the caveat that its argument is an HTML string instead of something useful, but I might be confusing it with something else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cheap solution would be just adding `<li>` tag into the form like:

```
<%= f.fields_for :images do |image_builder| %>
 <li><%= render "images/form", :f => image_builder %></li>
<% end %>
```

I am not sure if you can completely eliminate the div tag by passing some params to `field_for`. But I think you can change the name of div class or id by passing the html block, like in `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for @image, :as => :post, :url => post_image_path, 
   :html => { :class => "new_image", :id => "new_image" } do |f| %>
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion before posting, but the fields_for call actually wraps anything that's inside it in the aforementioned div tags. So I would get something like <ul> <div> <li>..</li> </div> </ul>

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. This is actually the answer. The problem was not simple_form... it's that the form was actually using the nested_form plugin as well... so it was simple_NESTED_form_for tag, this causes the fields to be wrapped in the div...

Answer (score 12):

The following disables the wrapper:

```
f.fields_for :images, wrapper:false do |image_builder|
```

then you can add your own wrapper in the builder block.

Comment: I was surprised to see that nested_form doesn't give you an options[:class] to alter this. It's hard coded to 'fields' [here](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form/blob/master/lib/nested_form/builder_mixin.rb#L91).

Answer (score -1):

You said you're using simple_form then you should be saying `<%= f.simple_fields_for..`. Have you tried using `wrapper_html` option:

```
<%= f.input :name, :label_html => { :class => 'upcase strong' },
  :input_html => { :class => 'medium' }, :wrapper_html => { :class => 'grid_6 alpha' } %>
```

**Edit 1:**
From SimpleForm documentation:

**Wrapper**

[SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) allows you to add a wrapper which contains the label, error, hint and input. The first step is to configure a wrapper tag:

```
SimpleForm.wrapper_tag = :p
```

And now, you don't need to wrap your f.input calls anymore:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Edit 2:

And there is this config option with which you can say what css class to use with the wrapper elements:

**config/initializers/simple_form.rb**

```
# CSS class to add to all wrapper tags.
config.wrapper_class = :input
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, SimpleForm.wrapper_tag only affects individual inputs :/ fields_for is wrapping my entire nested form in a <div class="fields"> tag. The inputs in the nested form itself are alright.

Comment: The problem was that the form was using the nested_form gem generator as well... this cause the fields_for call to be wrapped. thanks!